# How to process data in chunks(Pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function:

```
def extract_named_entities(note):
    """
    Extract the named entities identified in a given note.
    """
    doc = nlp(note)
    return [ent.text for ent in doc.ents]

df['named_entities'] = df['NOTE'].apply(extract_named_entities)

e_df = df.explode('named_entities').reset_index(drop=True)
```

The each row of `df['NOTE']` contains a **2500** word paragraph. I want to optimize this function as this function works quickly for 5-10 rows. But, I have 6400 rows and it is taking a lot of time. I

Is it possible to apply chunks or any other optimization techniques or is it possible to avoid the usage of lists?

Comment: Apply is just an internal for-loop over every row in your dataframe. Pandas is optimized to efficiently handle numeric data, strings are usually quite slow. As you use strings, optimiziation via numpy or numba is also not really possible. Have you measured what exactly is slow? Is it calling the function 6400 times? The apply function (which needs to append the results to a `pandas.Series`)? Or maybe adding the Series to your dataframe? I assume calling the `nlp()` function repeatedly is what takes so much time. So nothing about pandas.

Comment: Is it possible to minimize by applying chunks or the processing will be same

Comment: What do you mean by chunks? Each row is processed one after the other. So of course if you only process 100 rows at the time, this is faster than processing all rows, but then you have to perform this 25 times. In total this is even slower as you have to modify your dataframe several times.

Comment: At a guess, between 640x and 1200x as long?

Answer (score 4):

I assume in your code `nlp` is really a SpaCy model.  In that case, your function does not extract entities. It extracts the SpaCy tokens of a "NOTE". If each text has about 2500 words, then you get more than 2500 tokens per row, and for each row `nlp(...)` is called (which is rather slow).

When you then explode those lists, you get a dataframe or series of 6400 * 2500 rows (and if you keep the other columns, this means you get a pretty huge and hugely redundant dataframe).

The `pandas.apply` call just iterates over the rows - it's just a loop. The only way to make the extract function (as-is) faster is to parallellize it. Simply vectorizing the function (so it operates on the column as a whole, not just on separate cells) would not be enough, since the real work is done inside the `nlp(...)` call and you cannot change the implementation of `nlp`.

If you just want the tokens, then the extract function itself can be optimized by defining it as:

```
def extract_tokens(text):
    return [x.text for x in nlp.tokenize(text)]
```

Applied to about 6800 rows each of up to about 3200 words (with a mean of about 730 words), this runs in a total of less than 6 secs (on an Apple M2 laptop), whereas `nlp(text)` is significantly slower (more than 10x as slow).